# List of De-Duped Lists, Remove Nested Elements

Tags: python

Assume I have a de-duped sorted list of unique lists:

```
a_list = [
          ["A","B"],
          ["A","B","C"],
          ["A","B","C","D"],
          ["X"],
          ["X","Y","Z"],
]
```

How can I remove the larger overlapping lists to only leave the smallest lists?

```
desired_list = [
          ["A","B"],
          ["X"],
]
```

Comment: `desired_list = [a for a in a_list if not any(all(i in a for i in b) and len(a) > len(b) for b in a_list)]`

Comment: or: `[a for a in a_list if not any(set(a) > set(b) for b in a_list)]`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `set` to keep track of the first elements, and filter out sublists whose first elements have already been seen.

```
seen = set()
desired_list = []
for sublist in a_list:
    first = sublist[0]
    if first in seen:
        continue
    desired_list.append(sublist)
    seen.add(first)
```

**Note**: This solution assumes the sublists are not empty and their first elements are hashable. It also assumes that `a_list` is like you showed and doesn't contain any situations where a shorter list comes later, e.g. `["A", "B", "C"], ["A", "D"]`.